# Error trying to change language

Tags: joomla, error, language

When I try to enter the localization management section, I encounter such an error.

Sorry, due to an error, we are unable to fulfill your request at the moment. You may want to contact your administrator or service provider with more details about what action you were performing when this occurred.
DB Error: insufficient permissions.

We use the newest version of joomla and Civicrm that i downloaded on the offical sites.

Tell me how to solve this problem?

Comment: Still sometimes such errors take off.
https://yadi.sk/i/v2enm4XcqK94_A

Comment: better if you paste screenshots

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would check your MySQL permissions - my guess is that you lack the `CREATE VIEW` permission, which is necessary for multilingual installs. Here is a [full list of MySQL permissions needed](https://docs.civicrm.org/sysadmin/en/latest/requirements/#mysql-permissions).

If you go to CiviCRM's **Administer menu » System Settings » Debugging and Error Handling**, you can turn on Debugging and Backtrace, which will give you a longer error message detailing exactly which permission is missing.  If my answer doesn't fix your problem, please do so, then edit your question to include the additional info.

Comment: I do not have knowledge of working with mysql tables
Could you tell us step by step how can I set permissions in MySQL?
But the log, the errors that I received, including the recommended options:
https://yadi.sk/d/caeAFEoq9y2umw

Comment: From your backtrace, the permission that's missing is `CREATE TRIGGER`.  Unfortunately, setting up MySQL permissions is dependent on your host, so I can't give you better advice.  However, you can talk to your hosting company and tell them you need `CREATE TRIGGER` permissions.  Be aware that some low-cost hosting companies will not give you this permission.

Comment: Thank. Posted in support.